# Dart Multiple Constructors

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it really not possible to create multiple constructors for a class in dart?

in my Player Class, If I have this constructor

```
Player(String name, int color) {
    this._color = color;
    this._name = name;
}
```

Then I try to add this constructor:

```
Player(Player another) {
    this._color = another.getColor();
    this._name = another.getName();
}
```

I get the following error:

> The default constructor is already defined.

I'm not looking for a workaround by creating one Constructor with a bunch of non required arguments.

Is there a nice way to solve this?

Comment: As an unrelated comment, you should probably be using getters for `color` and `name`, not `getColor()` and `getName()` methods. If the values never change, you can use a single public field like `class Player { final String name; final int color; Player(this.name, this.color); }`.

Comment: I'm new to dart and not yet used to these kind of standards, but thanks , I will give it a try.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You can only have one **unnamed** [constructor](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#constructors), but you can have any number of additional [**named** constructors](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors)

```
class Player {
  Player(String name, int color) {
    this._color = color;
    this._name = name;
  }

  Player.fromPlayer(Player another) {
    this._color = another.getColor();
    this._name = another.getName();
  }  
}

new Player.fromPlayer(playerOne);
```

This constructor

```
  Player(String name, int color) {
    this._color = color;
    this._name = name;
  }
```

can be simplified to

```
  Player(this._name, this._color);
```

Named constructors can also be private by starting the name with `_`

```
class Player {
  Player._(this._name, this._color);

  Player._foo();
}
```

Constructors with `final` fields initializer list are necessary:

```
class Player {
  final String name;
  final String color;

  Player(this.name, this.color);

  Player.fromPlayer(Player another) :
    color = another.color,
    name = another.name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gunter. When I see the last syntax - I'm crying))) Dart if piece of shit)))

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev what part do you not like? How do you think it should be instead?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  I am not criticizing you, I am criticizing dart. It can be as in python, kotlin, swift and even as in java. The desired option with:
    prop1= ...,
    prop2= ....; looks ridiculous

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev I didn't take it as criticism at all. I was genuinely curious what bothers you. I was working full-time with Dart when this was implemented and it made life easier. I never thought about it again since. Dart makes strong guaranties about the order of when which fields are initialized and when it's safe to access them. AFAIK to uphold that, this particular design was chosen. I don't know the other languages you mentioned well enough to point out specifics why it's "better" there. Python is dynamically typed, so it's not a good candidate for comparison. The others are though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Good to hear it. I'm unfamilar with flutter and dart. My main area is Android and Kotlin, but last N month I have been working with Flutter in my startup and I really feel pain time to time. Syntax of Dart is a hello from 2006. After Kotlin it looks like a Javascript or Pascal. I still don't understand some dart constructions and I really tried to did it)) async and ascyn*, _ instead private, missing protected, and of course constructors... In the comparing of Dart and Kotlin, for example, I liked dart only in the single moment - ternary operator and nothing more

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev I understand the pain, but it's common with new stuff. One of Darts goals and advantages is that it can compiled into efficient JS, so it's not too surprising some things remind you of JS. Dart has a somewhat tumultuous history. Some things are remnants of that. Dart 2 became a completely different language than what Dart 1 was. I think there is nothing wrong with async/async*. The whole async story is really great in Dart. _ was discussed a lot. I personally like it. `@protected` was an afterthought and never got real attention. Metaprogramming will be a huge step forward.

Comment: The Dart team consists of great people that I admire a lot.  Also Flutter is really great and worth any drawbacks of Dart. I think Flutter wouldn't be that good if they had used any other language. Dart has great features behind the syntax.

Comment: Thank you, @GünterZöchbauer. I will give flutter chance to change my mind

Answer (score 12):

If your class uses final parameters the accepted answer will not work. This does:

```
class Player {
  final String name;
  final String color;

  Player(this.name, this.color);

  Player.fromPlayer(Player another) :
    color = another.color,
    name = another.name;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already used a constructor with params in the project and now you figured out that you need some no params default constructor you can add an empty constructor.

```
class User{
String name;

   User({this.name}); //This you already had before
   User.empty(); //Add this later 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Try the below code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

```
class MyClass {
  //These two are private attributes
  int _age;
  String _name;

  //This is a public attribute
  String defaultName = "My Default Name!";

  //Default constructor
  MyClass() {
    _age = 0;
    _name = "Anonymous";
  }

  MyClass.copyContructor(MyClass fromMyClass) {
    this._age = fromMyClass._age;
    this._name = fromMyClass._name;
  }

  MyClass.overloadedContructor(String name, int age) {
    this._age = age;
    this._name = name;
  }

  MyClass.overloadedContructorNamedArguemnts({String name, int age}) {
    this._age = age;
    this._name = name;
  }

  //Overriding the toString() method
  String toString() {
    String retVal = "Name:: " + _name + " | " + "Age:: " + _age.toString();
    return retVal;
  }
}

//The execution starts from here..
void main() {
  MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();

  //Cannot access oprivate attributes
  //print(myClass1.name);
  //print(myClass1.age);

  //Can access the public attribute
  print("Default Name:: " + myClass1.defaultName);

  print(myClass1.toString());

  MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass.copyContructor(myClass1);

  print(myClass2.toString());

  MyClass myClass3 = new MyClass.overloadedContructor("Amit", 42);

  print(myClass3.toString());

  MyClass myClass4 =
      new MyClass.overloadedContructorNamedArguemnts(age: 42, name: "Amit");

  print(myClass4.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dart doesn't support parameter overloading (having multiple functions of the same name but with different parameters). This applies to constructors as well - that's the reason why in SDK there're so many classes with named constructors.

In Dart you can use Default Constructor, Named Constructor, Factory Method and Static Method to instantiate classes:

```
class A {
  // Default constructor
  A() : msg = '1';
  
  // Named constructor with positional param
  A.message(this.msg);
  
  // Factory method with named param
  factory A.underscore({String msg = ''}) {
    return A.message('_'+msg);
  }
  
  // Factory method with arrow func body
  static A bang(msg) => A.message('!'+msg); 
  
  final String msg;
}

void main() {
  print(A().msg);
  print(A.message('2').msg);
  print(A.underscore(msg: '3').msg);
  print(A.bang('4').msg);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
_3
!4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [factory constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors)

```
factory Player.fromPlayer(Player another) => Player(another.name, another.color);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49691200/10204932) already specified in his answer:

> You can only have one unnamed constructor, but you can have any number of additional named constructors in Flutter.

- By using named constructor you can create multiple constructors in the same class.
- Each constructor will have a unique name. So that you can identify each of them.

**Syntax for *named constructor*** :

```
class_name.constructor_name (arguments) { 
   // If there is a block of code, use this syntax

   // Statements
}

or

class_name.constructor_name (arguments); 
   // If there is no block of code, use this syntax
```

For more insights [Click Here](https://medium.com/jay-tillu/constructors-in-dart-4f972186c372)

To know about various types of constructors in Flutter [Click Here](https://bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-constructors/)

Comment: please specify if I had mistaken somewhere so that I can improve or else remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i had found solution to solve this problem depend on checked the type of data you are passed it to function

Try this  [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64315726/8888756)

Answer (score 0):

```html
Class User{
      User();
      User.fromName(this.name);
      
      String? name;
    }
```

Comment: There are **eight existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with **two hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some more elaborated property calculation (I'm a Swift guy), you can do like this:

```
class FooProvider {
  int selectedFoo;

  FooProvider(List<String> usageObjects)
      : selectedFoo = firstOne(usageObjects);

  static int firstOne(List<String> usageObjects) {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
make the properties you need to pass to the other constructor as optionals.

```
class Person{
  String name;
  int? age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  Person.veryOld(this.name){
    age = 60;
  }

  @override String toString() {
    return "name: $name\nage: $age";
  }
}
```