# How can I get a default and a parameterized constructor inside the same class in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that in C++ we could have both of the constructors without a problem. In Dart when I'm trying to write two constructors, it says "The default constructor is already defined"

```
class Human {
  double height;
  int age;

  Human()
  {
    height = 0;
      age = 0;
  }

  Human (double startingheight){        //The default constructor is already defined
    height = startingheight;
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691163/dart-multiple-constructors

Answer (score 1):

Dart doesn't support methods/functions overload and [will not have it](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26488) in any visible future.

What you can do here is to make the parameters [optional](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters) with default value:

Either as positional arguments:

```dart
class Human {
  double height = 175;
  Human([this.height]);
}

var human1 = Human(); 
var human = Human(180);
```

or named:

```dart
class Human {
  final double height;
  Human({this.height = 175});
}

var human1 = Human(); 
var human = Human(height: 180);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```dart
//Using Default parameter values
Human({this.height = 0.0, this.age = 0});

// Named constructor
Human.startingHeight(double startingHeight){ 
    height = startingHeight;
    age = 0;//or don't use this if you want it null
}
```

For more info check out this page: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Answer (score 0):

```
class Human{
      Human(double height, int color) {
      this._height = height;
      this._color = color;
   }

   Human.fromHuman(Human another) {
      this._height = another.getHeight();
      this._color = another.getColor();
   }  
}

new Human.fromHuman(man);
```

This constructor can be simplified

```
Human(double height, int age) {
   this._height = height;
   this._age = age;
}
```

to

```
Human(this._height, this._age);
```

Named constructors can also be private by starting the name with `_`

Constructors with `final` fields initializer list are necessary:

```
class Human{
  final double height;
  final int age;

  Human(this.height, this.age);

  Human.fromHuman(Human another) :
    height= another.height,
    age= another.age;
}
```